# Read and write an ArrayList to a .txt file

Tags: java, file, arraylist, bufferedreader, filewriter

I can't get this part of my project to work. (fileOut() and fileIn() methods). I would appreciate any help!

I am trying to construct a method to open a text file and to write the details of an ArrayList of type  to it.

I am also trying to construct a second method to open the text file containing details of all the bank’s accounts and uses the incoming data to create BankAccount objects using a BankAccount Constructor and storing each account in an ArrayList.

Please note that other methods in the class need to use the information stored in the arraylist(s).
Here is the main bit of code to focus on(reading and writing):

```
public void fileOut()
{
    File fileName = new File("BankAccountFiles.txt");
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        int numEntries = bankAccArrayList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
            output.write(bankAccArrayList.get(i).toString() + "\n"); 
        }
        output.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File cannot be created");
    }
}


public void fileIn()
{
    ArrayList<BankAccount> aList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    String line;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BankAccountFiles.txt"));
        if(!input.ready()) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            aList.add(line);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the whole class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyBankController
{

    private ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccArrayList;


    public MyBankController() 
    {   
        bankAccArrayList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    }

    public void createAccount (String accNum, String custName)
    {   
        bankAccArrayList.add(new BankAccount( accNum,custName));
        printAccountDetails(bankAccArrayList.get(bankAccArrayList.size()-1));
    }

    private void printAccountDetails(BankAccount incomingAcc)
    {   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,incomingAcc.toString(),"Account Details",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void listAllAccounts()
    {  
        String outputStr = "List of all accounts :\n\n";

        for(BankAccount account :  bankAccArrayList){

            outputStr += account + "\n\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,outputStr,"List of all Accounts",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void listAllActiveAccounts()
    {  
        String outputStr = "List of all active accounts :\n\n";
        for(BankAccount account :  bankAccArrayList){

            if(account.getActive()) {

                outputStr += account + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,outputStr,"List of all Active Accounts",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    private int getIndex(String bankAccNum)

    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < bankAccArrayList.size(); i++) {

            if (bankAccNum.equals(bankAccArrayList.get(i).getAccNumber()))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bank Account Number: " + bankAccNum + " is invalid","Error wrong account number",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return -1;
    }

    public void makeWithdrawal(String accNumber, double amount)
    {   
        if(getIndex(accNumber) != -1){ 

            bankAccArrayList.get(getIndex(accNumber)).makeWithdraw(amount);
        }
    }

    public void makeLodgement(String accNumber, double amount)
    {   
        if(getIndex(accNumber) != -1){ 

            bankAccArrayList.get(getIndex(accNumber)).makeLodgement(amount);
        }
    }

    public  void displayAccount(String accNumber)
    {   
        if(getIndex(accNumber) != -1){ 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,(bankAccArrayList.get(getIndex(accNumber)).toString()),"Accounts Details",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public  void closeAccount(String accNumber)
    {   
        if(getIndex(accNumber) != -1){ 

            bankAccArrayList.get(getIndex(accNumber)).closeAccount();
        }
    }

     public  void removeAccount(String accNumber)
    {   

        int index = getIndex(accNumber);

        if(index != -1){ 

            BankAccount myAcc = bankAccArrayList.get(index);

            if ((myAcc.getActive() == false) && (myAcc.getAccBalance() == 0)){

                bankAccArrayList.remove(index);

            }else if((myAcc.getActive() == false) && (myAcc.getAccBalance() > 0)){

                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," This account has a balance,do you wish to withdraw this balance " + 
                        "so as to remove the account ?"," Balance in inactive account",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                    myAcc.setActive();
                    myAcc.makeWithdraw(myAcc.getAccBalance());
                    myAcc.setActive();
                    bankAccArrayList.remove(index);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Removed","Confirmation",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }

            } else if((myAcc.getActive() == true) && (myAcc.getAccBalance() == 0)){

                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," This account still has an active status, do you wish to change its status so as to remove account ?"  
                    ,"Account Active",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

                if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                    myAcc.setActive();
                    bankAccArrayList.remove(index);                              
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Removed","Confirmation",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                }

            } else{

                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null," This account still has an active status and a balance, do you wish to close the account so as remove it" 
                    ,"Account Active with Balance",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                    myAcc.closeAccount();
                    bankAccArrayList.remove(index);                                
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Removed","Confirmation",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }                
            }
        }
    }


        public void customerInterface() 
    {
        String accNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your account number","Account Login",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if(getIndex(accNumber) != -1)
        {
             String numOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please select an option below:\n\n" + 
            " [1] Make a lodgment:\n\n [2] Make a withdrawal:\n\n [3] Display account details:\n\n" +
            " [4] Close account:\n\n [5] Exit","MyBank ATM",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (numOption == null) //User presses cancel or 'x'.
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye.","MyBank System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 1) //Converts numOption from String to Integer.
            {
                //Brings up lodgement interface
                String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount you would like to lodge.");
                makeLodgement(accNumber, Double.parseDouble(amount)); // Lodges amount into account.
                customerInterface(); 
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 2)
            {
             String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount you wish to withdraw.");
             makeWithdrawal(accNumber, Double.parseDouble(amount)); //Call on makeWithdrawl method.
             customerInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 3)
            {
                displayAccount(accNumber); //Calls on displayAccount method.
                customerInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 4)
            {
                closeAccount(accNumber); //Call on close account method.
                customerInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 5)
            {
                return; //Exits system.
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) > 5 || Integer.parseInt(numOption) < 1) //If number enter is outside of 1-5.
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a number between 1-5 and try again.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              customerInterface();
            }   
        }
    }


    public void bankInterface()
    {
            String numOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please select an option below:\n\n" + 
            " [1] Display All Accounts:\n\n [2] Display All Active Accounts:\n\n [3] Open a New Account:\n\n" +
            " [4] Close an Existing Account:\n\n [5] Run Start of Day:\n\n [6] Run End of Day:\n\n [7] Exit:","MyBank System",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (numOption == null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye.","MyBank System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); //User presses cancel or 'x'.
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 1) //Converts numOption from String to Integer.
            {
                //Displays all accounts.
                listAllAccounts();
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 2)
            {
                //Display all active accounts.
                listAllActiveAccounts();
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 3)
            {
                //Open a new account
                String accNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please allocate an account number:");
                String custName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the customers name:");
                createAccount (accNum, custName);
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 4)
            {
                //Close an existing account.
                String accNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the account number you would like to close:");
                closeAccount(accNumber);
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 5)
            {
                //Run start of day file.
                fileIn();
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 6)
            {
                //Run end of day file.
                fileOut();
                bankInterface();
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) == 7)
            {
                //Exits system.
                return;
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(numOption) > 7 ||Integer.parseInt(numOption) < 1) //If user enters number outside of 1-7.
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a number between 1-7 and try again.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                bankInterface();
            }
    }


    public void fileOut()
    {
        File fileName = new File("BankAccountFiles.txt");
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
            Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int numEntries = bankAccArrayList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
                output.write(bankAccArrayList.get(i).toString() + "\n"); 
            }
            output.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File cannot be created");
        }
    }


    public void fileIn()
    {
        ArrayList<BankAccount> aList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        String line;
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BankAccountFiles.txt"));
            if(!input.ready()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                aList.add(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your errors or what is going wrong?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add it actually.

Comment: in the fileIn() method, the line:
aList.add(line);

It has numerous errors for that line.
no suitable method found for add(java.lang.string)
method.java.util.collection.add(BankAccount) is not applicable

Comment: You have parse the line in your file into a BanckAccount before you can store it in a your list.

Answer (score 1):

In your `fileIn` method, you're trying to add a String to an `ArrayList` of type `BankAccount`.
 Instead of `aList.add(line)`, you should use `aList.add(new BankAccount(line))`.
Assuming your `BankAccount` constructor takes only a single String parameter, this should work.
Full method:

```
  public void fileIn()
    {
        List<BankAccount> aList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        String line;
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BankAccountFiles.txt"));
            if(!input.ready()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                aList.add(new BankAccount(line));
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    aList.forEach(System.out::println); // Java8
    }
```

I've also changed your `aList` to use the `List` interface, and added a lambda to print each value in `aList` at the end.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. I appreciate it alot. My BankAccount constructor takes two string parameters. Any further suggestions?

At the moment, i'm getting an error from the line:
aList.add(new BankAccount(line));

The error is: constructor BankAccount in class BankAccount cannot be applied to the given types:
required: java.lang.String, java.lang.String
found: java.lang.String

Comment: @DylanHig I imagined so. You are writing `BankAccount.toString()` to the file and then reading it as a single string. You need to either write the 2nd parameter of `BankAccount` to the file and use it as the 2nd constructor parameter, or read it from someplace else. For the sake of the example just try calling `aList.add(new BankAccount(line, "123"))` to see what I mean.